# Free software to record speedpaints

Tags: gratis, screen-recording

I have Krita as painting software.

I need a free recording software to record me creating my art.

Comment: What's your operating system?

Comment: I think that mentioning Kritas is distracting; just keep it to "looking for screen recording software". You can probably Google round to find what gamers use & that will be fine. If it is for Windows, I can certainly recommend a great one.

Answer (score 1):

[FFMPEG](https://ffmpeg.org/) has the ability to do this with its [gdigrab](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#gdigrab) device. FFMPEG is:

- free, gratis & open source
- Cross Platform, (will work on Windows, OS-X & Linux),
- can be used for a lot more video related tasks.

To record your whole screen, in the command window or terminal:

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 10 -i desktop [output]
```

Or to just record the Krita window:

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 25 -i title=Krita [output]
```

Where [output] is the filename that you would like to record to including the extension, e.g.: `session1.mpeg`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use command line tools, you can use [ShareX](https://getsharex.com/) which is open source and uses FFmpeg to capture your screen. Later you can use something like [Kdenlive](https://kdenlive.org/) to speed up your video.

[image]